# How does packed-switch work on Android as smali produced by apktool?

Tags: android, smali

I'm trying to reverse engineer an apk with `apktool d` and the smali it produces contains packed-switch statements which I don't fully understand. A method contains:

`packed-switch v0, :pswitch_data_0`

Followed later in the code with labels like `:pswitch_X`
 where X is a number and at the end of the method with:

```
:pswitch_data_0
.packed-switch 0x7f060395
    :pswitch_4
    :pswitch_5
    :pswitch_1
.end packed-switch
```

What exactly does this do? It looks like a list of places to jump to, but on what condition? What does it do with 0x7f060395?

Answer (score 16):

Switches are in two parts, as you noticed. The second part you listed is the payload pseudo-instruction, that contains all the switch cases. The first part is a packed-switch instruction, which defines the register containing the value to check, and refers to a payload instruction using a label.

For a packed-switch, the case values in the payload pseudo-instruction are sequential, and only the first value is actually given (in this case, 0x7f060395)

For your example specifically, when the packed-switch instruction is executed, it will check the value of the v0 register against the 3 cases in the payload. If the value is 0x7f060395, it will jump to :pswitch_4, if 0x7f060396, it will jump to :pswitch_5, etc.

If the value of the register didn't match any of the cases, then execution will continue with the next instruction after the packed-switch instruction (the one with the register and label, not the payload pseudo-instruction).

The sparse-switch instruction is similar, except that its payload instruction has an explicit value associated with each case, instead of using sequential key values.

You can find all the nitty-gritty details in the [dalvik-bytecode](http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html) document.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I reproduced your answer on [forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45212756) as I asked the same question there. If this offends you let me know and I'll remove it.

Comment: No worries :). It's amusing that I'm posting vicariously on xda now, via you. (I used to be a regular, waaay back in the g1 days).

Comment: I'm assuming if it matches none, then execution just continues?

Comment: Oh yes,  so you did, oops :)